# How safe is running "fsck -f -y"?

Tags: command-line, filesystem

I want to check the consistency of a file system and **fix the errors**. What are the **safety considerations** in running `fsck -f -y` on a file system?

Comment: fsck will try valiantly to not lose data, but it cannot perform miracles. It's reasonably safe...if your damage is reasonably ordinary.

Comment: Do `sudo fsck -N -y` to run it without making any changes first, if you are concerned. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/fsck.8.html is the general fsck man page; subordinate man pages exist for filesystem-specific checkers such as http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/fsck.ext3.8.html for ext2/3/4 filesystems.

Comment: "How safe is running fsck -f -y?"  Simple: we all make backups and know how to restore them so I say go for it. If it fails and ends badly you restore your backup.

Comment: What is this "safe" concept?

Comment: @waltinator: It means nothing will be corrupted as a result of running a procedure, or command, or software

Answer (score 3):

Neither flag is defined in the top-level [`fsck`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/fsck.8.html) documentation, so the most general answer is that it depends on the filesystem-specific fsck command you are using.

- For many fs-specific commands, in particular [`e2fsck`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/e2fsck.8.html) for ext2/ext3/ext4 file systems, the `-f` option is used to "Force checking even if the file system seems clean." This can make the command slower but is not expected to cause any harmful side effects in itself.
- The `-y` flag is described in the `fsck(8)` man page as follows (emphasis mine):

  > For some filesystem-specific checkers, the `-y` option  will  cause  the  fs-specific fsck  to  always  attempt  to fix any detected filesystem corruption automatically. **Sometimes an expert may be able to do better driving the fsck manually.**

  This implies that there is some risk involved: in some cases, the command may perform actions that would not be advised by an expert administrator.

  The `e2fsck` command has an alternative, `-p`, which can be used to "automatically fix any filesystem problems that can be safely fixed  without  human intervention." The command will exit with an error if any issues are detected that require further intervention.