# I can't go back to default mode

Tags: boot, fstab

Im completely new to this so I don't know anything.

As of 2 days ago I wasn't able to boot up normally anymore, it sent me straight to the emergency mode. I did research and found my way into the shell where I entered `mount -c` to check where the problem is (line 18, the one I wrote as a code line), then I entered `vi /etc/fstab` to try to solve it and again, I'm new to this, so I don't see anything wrong with it, feel free to tell me if I'm being too vague or I phrased something wrong, english isn't my first language, thx in advance.

```
/dev/md3 /media/DATOS   ext3 realtime, errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Comment: Probably totally unrelated, but once you've shared it, I point it out: that option: `realtime` as in "real time", should be instead `relatime`, as in, "relative time"

Comment: Also, between the `relatime,` and `errors=remount-ro` there should NOT be a space. It should be continuous like this: `relatime,errors=remount-ro`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether it will improve things at all or not, but I point out the problems I see with the line you posted anyways:

Instead of:

```
/dev/md3 /media/DATOS   ext3 realtime, errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

have it as:

```
/dev/md3 /media/DATOS   ext3 relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

I have changed `realtime` to `relatime` and **removed the space** between the two options delimited by the comma.

Point being, entries in `/etc/fstab` need to be divided into 6 columns (divided by spaces or tabs), as such:

```
<file system>   <mount point>   <type>   <options>   <dump>   <pass>
```

That's why it's important **not** to put spaces between the options: to maintain the six columns.

---

Regarding the first, "file system" column (in your entry `/dev/md3`):

Maybe this is not mandatory (I don't know), nevertheless I see that it's a tendency that people use **UUID**s (unique identifier) of partitions in that column.

That would alter your entire entry as such:

```
UUID=something123-like456-this789-asdfjkl   /media/DATOS   ext3   relatime,errors=remount-ro   0   1
```

You can find out the actual UUID for all the partitions with the following command:

```
sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL
```

Comment: Thx @Levente, I did as you told me but now idk how to save the changes

Comment: @Hermes Maybe I'm misunderstanding it, but, maybe this helps? https://askubuntu.com/q/1315288/1157519

Comment: @Hermes OMG you are using vi? :) If you don't know how to save a file in vi, then the best course of action is abandon the attempt! Myself being an experienced vim user, even I can accidentally mess up files with vim occasionally. But messing up `/etc/fstab` would make your life complicated! Close the window, hopefully that closes the file without saving. Alternatively try typing `Escape`, then `:q!`, then `Enter`. That's colon, a q letter and an exclamation mark. After that try editing with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and use the help I linked in my above comment.

Comment: Also, for the future, before editing important system files, it's best to make a safety copy of them. Something like `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak`

Comment: I'm not sure about this but while on the recovery console - given the restricted means of user interface - probably you could try skipping the part about changing the first column to the UUID. Maybe the UUID is just a cosmetic change that you could alter later, after you have recovered the system...

Comment: Well, now when I input mount -c it doesn't point out any errors, nevertheless, it still doesn't let me go to default mode, I'm completely lost

Comment: @Hermes I think you could think about posting a new question, including only the output that you are facing now. Linking back to this question would be useful, so that people will know that there was this episode with the `/etc/fstab`, even when it does not seem to impact things any more.

Comment: Yea, I could, but I don't even know what the problem is right now, i don't get a clear output and I don't know how to get one.

Comment: @Hermes Search this site or the web for "Ubuntu emergency mode + fsck". I had a problem once when it said "Welcome to emergency mode". The issue was fixed by letting the `fsck` disk utility fix my SSD. I'm not saying that's your problem, just that it might be one reason. `fsck` is no joke, so learn about it before using it. Start here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1188496/1157519 Most important: use a live USB installer device, and go into "Try Ubuntu without installing" mode. **First** mount your disk if you can, and **copy out your important data** from the internal disk to somewhere safe.